# how to install hadoop in windows 8

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

I would like to practice Hadoop in my Windows 8 and would like to practice all Hive , Pig , Hive , Hbase .Is there any package available to run all these things in my local ?

Please provide where to download and How to install it ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop and it's ecosystem(e.g. hive, hbase) is project of apache fund, so you can find them on the apache's website, [click here](http://hadoop.apache.org/). And the install document is [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.5.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html).

This is a basic problem, you should google it, because there are many blogs about hadoop and it's ecosystem. And then, the official document is the best practise.